# innerHTML does not work on span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next chunk of html on my html doc:

```
<p class="load-chart">Carregando Grafico<span id="load-dots">.</span></p>
```

When I try to use innerHTML on  I get the undefined msg, however when I use:

```
$('#load-dots').text("any new text");
```

it works fine.

### How I fixed

i solved this issue using:

```
$('span#load-dots').get(0).innerHTML;
```

Comment: There is a type `innterHTML` it should be `innerHTML`. Please clarify if this is code type or just so question type.

Comment: Sorry, I was a type error here in Stackkoverflow, I already have edit.

Comment: The actual syntax for jQuery is just `html()`

Comment: Try `$('#load-dots').get(0).innerHTML` But instead you could use `.html`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the solution with get(0).innerHTML works fine to me, thx :D

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` works fine:

```
<p class="load-chart">Carregando Grafico<span id="load-dots">.</span></p>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("load-dots").innerHTML = "some new text"
```

See: [.innerHTML - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p231jeo4/)

Also if you are already using jQuery, you should use `.html`. Its not a good practice to mix multiple approaches.

[.html() - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p231jeo4/1/)

Also note that `.html` or `.innerHTML`  is used to update markup of an element. If you just wish to update text, use `.text()`. Pure JS alternative would be `.textContent`

[.text() - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p231jeo4/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery one can invoke `.html()`,

```
$('#load-dots').html("any new text");
```